# Update Image Using AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing an issue with updating image to database using AJAX and a Modal, following are the details:
I have a main page named edit_employee.php, code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$ROOT='../../';
include('../config/db_connect.php');
require_once '../config/auth.php';
?>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title>Employee List | Employee Attendance Record System</title>
        <?php include('../includes/header.php') ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('../includes/nav_bar.php') ?>
        <div class="container-fluid admin" >
            <div class="alert alert-success">Employee Center-Edit</div>
            <div class="well col-lg-12 mt-5">
                <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="new_emp_btn"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add new </button> -->
                <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Joining Date</th>
                            <th>Picture</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $employee_qry=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE status='Active' ORDER BY employee_id ASC") or die(mysqli_error());
                            while($row=$employee_qry->fetch_array()){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['employee_id']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['first_name']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['designation']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['department']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($row['doj'])) ?></td>
                            <td><img <?php echo 'src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['picture'] ).'"' ?> height="50px" width="75px" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success edit_employee" data-id="<?php echo $row['employee_id']?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger remove_employee" data-id="<?php echo $row['employee_id']?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--MODALS-->
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/astrahrms/admin/employees/modals/modal_editemp.php'); ?>
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/astrahrms/admin/employees/modals/modal_deleteemp.php'); ?>
<!--MODALS END-->
</body>
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/astrahrms/admin/employees/scripts/edit_emp.php'); ?>
</html>
```

page has a button having class edit_employee which opens a modal on click, I used javascript and ajax for this (ajax contained in php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/astrahrms/admin/employees/scripts/edit_emp.php')), below is the code for your reference:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.edit_employee').click(function () {
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
  // AJAX request
  $.ajax({
   url: './functions/get_employee.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {id:id},
   success: function(response){
     // Add response in Modal body
     $('.modal-body').html(response);
     // Display Modal
     $('#editmodal').modal('show');
   }
 });
});
});
</script>
```

This opens a modal with some employee information and employee image, I put this modal in get_employee.php, code below for your reference:

```
<style>
label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 155px;
  text-align: right;
}
.form-control{
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.profile-pic-div{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 350px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(12, 189, 189);
    display:table-cell;
}
#photo{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#file{
    display: none;
}
#uploadBtn{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: auto;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: wheat;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.col-auto img{
  background-color:rgb(12, 189, 189);
  width: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
}
</style>
<!-- PICTURE sCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#editmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    location.reload();
});
});
//declearing html elements
const imgDiv = document.querySelector('.profile-pic-div');
const img = document.querySelector('#photo');
const file = document.querySelector('#file');
const uploadBtn = document.querySelector('#uploadBtn');
//if user hover on img div
imgDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    uploadBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
});
//if we hover out from img div
imgDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    uploadBtn.style.display = "none";
});
//lets work for image showing functionality when we choose an image to upload
//when we choose a foto to upload
file.addEventListener('change', function(){
    //this refers to file
    const choosedFile = this.files[0];
    if (choosedFile) {
        const reader = new FileReader(); //FileReader is a predefined function of JS
        reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
            img.setAttribute('src', reader.result);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(choosedFile);
    }
});
</script>
<?php
$ROOT='../../';
    include '../../config/db_connect.php';
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        include_once('../../config/db_connect.php');
        if (!$conn) {
          die('Could not connnect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
      }
            $query="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id = '$id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            ?>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-success" id="myTab">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link  text-info border_bottom border_bottom_info active"  data-toggle="tab" href="#personal">Personal Information</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link text-info"  data-toggle="tab" href="#company">Company Information</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link text-info"  data-toggle="tab" href="#payroll">Payroll Information</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link text-info"  data-toggle="tab" href="#incentives">Benefits/Incentives</a>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content container-fluid" id="myTabContent">
                    <!--Personal Information-->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="personal">
                        <div class="well col-lg-12"  id="displaydata">
                            <!--CONTENT HERE-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 float-left">
                                                <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">First Name: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="firstname" name="firstname" required value="<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Last Name: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="lastname" name="lastname" required value="<?php echo $row['last_name'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">CNIC Number: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="cnic" name="cnic" required value="<?php echo $row['cnic'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Permanent Address: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="paddress" name="paddress" required value="<?php echo $row['permanent_address'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Local Address: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="laddress" name="laddress" required value="<?php echo $row['local_address'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Mobile Number: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="mobile" name="mobile" required value="<?php echo $row['mobile'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Emergency Number: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="emergency" name="emergency" required value="<?php echo $row['emergency_contact'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Qualification: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="qualification" name="qualification" required value="<?php echo $row['qualification'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Date of Birth: </label>
                                        <input type="date" class=" form-control w-50 " id="dob" name="dob" required value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['dob'])) ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Blood Group: </label>
                                        <select class="w-50 my-1 form-control" style="cursor:pointer;" id="bg">
                                            <option selected><?php echo $row['blood_group'];?></option>
                                            <option value="A+">A+</option>
                                            <option value="O+">O+</option>
                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                            <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                            <option value="O-">O-</option>
                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                            <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                        <label for="" class="mr-2">Special Notes: </label>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="sn" name="sn" required value="<?php echo $row['note'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="form-group col-auto">
                                        <label for="file" id="uploadBtn" class="mr-2">Employee Picture</label>
                                        <div class="profile-pic-div">
                                            <img <?php echo 'src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['picture'] ).'"' ?> id="photo" >
                      <input type="file" name="ProfileImage" id="file" />
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer mt-1">
                                <button data-id="<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>" class="btn btn-success persinfo" name="persinfo" id="<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save & Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- Company Information-->
                <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="company">
                <div class="well col-lg-12" id="displaydata1">
                    <!--CONTENT HERE-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 float-left">
                            <div class=" col-auto mt-3">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Employee ID: </label>
                                <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50  my-1  " name="employeeid" id="employeeid" required value="<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>" disabled>
                                <!-- <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/settings.png" alt=""> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Select Block: </label>
                                <select class="w-50 form-control" style="cursor:pointer;" id="sblock">
                                    <option selected><?php echo $row['block'];?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Select Department: </label>
                                <select class="w-50 form-control" style="cursor:pointer;" id="sdpt">
                                    <option selected><?php echo $row['department'];?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Select Designation: </label>
                                <select class="w-50 form-control" style="cursor:pointer;" id="sdesig">
                                    <option selected ><?php echo $row['designation'];?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Employee Type: </label>
                                <select class="w-50 form-control" style="cursor:pointer;" id="semptyp">
                                    <option selected><?php echo $row['employee_type'];?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Email: </label>
                                <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="email" name="email" required value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Date of Joining: </label>
                                <input type="date" class=" form-control w-50 " id="doj" name="doj" required value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['doj']));?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 float-left">
                            <h5 class="mt-3 ml-3" style="color:#636c78;">Employee Shift Information</h5>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Set Shift: </label>
                                <select class="form-control w-50" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                    <option selected><?php echo $row['shift'];?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $shid=$row['shift'];
                            $query1="SELECT * FROM tbl_shifts WHERE shift_id ='$shid'";
                            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
                            $row1 = $result1->fetch_array();
                             ?>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Start Time: </label>
                                <input type="time" class=" form-control w-50 " id="stime" name="stime" value="<?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($row1['st_tm']));?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">End Time: </label>
                                <input type="time" class=" form-control w-50 " id="etime" name="etime" value="<?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($row1['end_tm']));?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                                <label for="" class="mr-2">Weekday: </label>
                                <select class="form-control w-50" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                    <option selected><?php echo $row1['weekday'];?></option>
                                    <option>Monday</option>
                                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                                    <option>Wednesday</option>
                                    <option>Thursday</option>
                                    <option>Friday</option>
                                    <option>Saturday</option>
                                    <option>Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer mt-5">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" name="save_emp" id="save_emp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save & Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Payroll Information-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="payroll">
            <div class="well col-lg-12" id="displaydata1">
                <!--CONTENT HERE-->
                <?php
                $empid=$row['employee_id'];
                $query2="SELECT * FROM emp_salary WHERE employee_id ='$empid'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
                $row2 = $result2->fetch_array();
                 ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 float-left">
                        <h5 class="mt-3 ml-3" style="color:#636c78;">Monthly Salary Information</h5>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Gross Salary: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="gsalary" name="gsalary" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row2['gross_salary'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Basic Salary: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="bsalary" name="bsalary" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row2['basic_salary'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">House Rent Allowance: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="hra" name="hra" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row2['hra'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Utility Allowance: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="ua" name="ua" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row2['ua'];?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $query3="SELECT * FROM emp_allowed_leaves WHERE employee_id ='$empid'";
                    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
                    $row3 = $result3->fetch_array();
                     ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 float-left">
                        <h5 class="mt-3 ml-3" style="color:#636c78;">Allowed Leaves Information</h5>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Annual Leaves: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="aleaves" name="aleaves" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row3['annual'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Casual Leaves: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="cleaves" name="cleaves" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row3['casual'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Sick Leaves: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="sleaves" name="sleaves" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row3['sick'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mt-1">
                            <label for="" class="mr-2">Maternity Leaves: </label>
                            <input type="text" class=" form-control w-50 " id="mleaves" name="mleaves" placeholder="0" required value="<?php echo $row3['maternity'];?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer mt-5">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" name="save_emp" id="save_emp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save & Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Incentives Information-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="incentives">
        <div class="well col-lg-12" id="displaydata1">
            <!--CONTENT HERE-->
            <?php
            $query4="SELECT * FROM emp_benefits WHERE employee_id ='$empid'";
            $result4 = mysqli_query($conn,$query4);
            $row4 = $result4->fetch_array();
             ?>
            <div class="col-lg-6 float-left check">
                <h5 class="mt-3 ml-3" style="color:#636c78;">Company Allowed Benefits</h5>
                <div class="col-auto mt-3 ml-4">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="gli" id="gli" onclick="return myfun()" value="gli" <?php if ($row4['gli'] == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
                    <label class="form-check-inline" style="width: 150px;" style="text-align:left;">Group Life Insurance</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto mt-1 ml-4">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="eobi" id="eobi" onclick="return myfun()" value="eobi" <?php if ($row4['eobi'] == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2" style="text-align:left;">EOBI  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto mt-1 ml-4">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pessi" id="pessi" onclick="return myfun()"  value="pessi" <?php if ($row4['pessi'] == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2" style="text-align:left;">PESSI  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto mt-1 mb-5 ml-4">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="overtime" id="overtime" onclick="return myfun()"  value="overtime" <?php if ($row4['overtime'] == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2" style="text-align:left;">Overtime  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 float-left check">
                <h5 class="mt-3 ml-3" style="color:#636c78;">Other Incentives</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer mt-5">
                <button class="btn btn-success" name="save_emp" id="save_emp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save & Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Employee Panel Ends-->
</div>
    <!-- SCRIPT -->
    <script src="../scripts/app.js"></script>
    <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/astrahrms/admin/employees/scripts/edit_emp.php'); ?>
<?php
        // echo json_encode($data);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

now I want to update the image in this opened modal on clicking button named persinfo, I want to assign all the values, in modal including newly selected image (using input named file, see code), to variables in AJAX and then call page update_employee.php page to execute the update query to change employee information and newly selected image in the opened modal.
Code for update_employee.php for your reference

```
include '../../config/db_connect.php';
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
        $paddress = $_POST['paddress'];
        $laddress = $_POST['laddress'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $emergency = $_POST['emergency'];
        $qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $bloodgroup = $_POST['bloodgroup'];
        $notes = $_POST['notes'];
        $query_run= $conn->query("UPDATE employee SET first_name='$firstname', last_name='$lastname', cnic='$cnic', permanent_address='$paddress', local_address='$laddress',mobile='$mobile',emergency_contact='$emergency',dob='$dob', qualification='$qualification',blood_group='$bloodgroup',note='$notes' WHERE employee_id='$id'");
        if ($query_run) {
                echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Regards

Comment: In your __edit_emp.php__ file, you are only posting the value `id` to your __update_employee.php__ file, here: `data: {id:id}`. None of the remaining form is posted. ((A side note, I urge you to not wait until later to secure your database, and use [PHP mysqli prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) from the start.))

Comment: Thanks for replying, First off, edit_emp.php holds the script action for calling a modal only, the data{id:id} is just to pass the selected id to modal page where it is used in a select query to fetch all the details and fill in the fields in modal based on the passed id. Secondly, thanks for suggestion on using PHP mysqli prepared statement which I'd definitely do.

Comment: Ok—that makes sense. Continuing on...I don't see file handling in the __update_employee.php__ file. How are you storing the image? I also don't see your Javascript `addEventListener` for the `persinfo` button. How are you posting the form data and image file to the __update_employee.php__ file on the server?

Comment: How are you storing the image? replying to this part, that is what I was actually asking for, I did not know how to store image using ajax which I figure out now. persinfo button has class which I call from another script. Thanks for your time though, much appreciated.